# No puedo acceder a volúmenes de Docker desde Linux (WSL2)

Tags: linux, docker, windows10, wsl

Yo uso Docker Desktop + WSL2. Tengo pleno acceso a los volúmenes de docker desde Windows usando esta ruta `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\`,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no desde el entorno Linux. A continuación les comparto una captura de pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco por la ayuda!

Comment: Porqué no accedes dirercto al sistema de archivos de linux en vez de hacerlo a través de un punto de montaje??

Comment: Cuando ejecuto `docker volume inspect template-react-app` obtengo la ruta de montaje `"Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/template-react-app/_data"`, que está vacía en el entorno linux. En lugar de `/var/lib/docker...` tengo `/var/lib/docker-desktop`. Es como el perro que se muerde la cola.